# in the CLR, is a local copy of an exe is created when running the exe from a remote folder?

Tags: c#, security

in the CLR, is a local copy of an exe is created when running the exe from a remote folder ?

if yes, where ?

Comment: What do you mean by remote? Over FTP or a windows share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CLR copies remote code to its download cache before executing it.

To view the content of the cache use "GacUtil /ldl"

To flush the cache use "GacUtil /cdl"

The GacUtil page has more detail http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Define remote?

.net's implementation involving running code from insecure locations, such as network folders etc. pushes the code into the partial trust zone (which is where any .net code running in your browser sits, or clickonce code).

It does not create a new copy of the exe, it runs it, and the the CLR will run in partial trust when the exe loads.

We need some more info...